# How can I speed up the Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

My laptop meets (exceeds) all requirements for running the Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator in VS2013, and it works fine, only it takes literally 15 minutes to start the emulator and then the app, still running slowly. Does anyone know how to improve the speed?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Hyper-V manager to disable checkpointing. Pick the emulator image in the Hyper-V manager and go to options/settings. This should speed up the Windows Phone OS loading/initializing phase.